# how to create restrictions on viewing posts on WordPress? something like medium

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to know what is the logic of the code that they use for this type of restriction and how can I do it on my WordPress website.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple example of how you could do this.

**Method A:**

You need to update the excerpt of each article.

Edit `single.php`:

```
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) :
        // Also you can include the template part here.
        the_content();
    else :
        // Show just the article excerpt.
        the_excerpt();
    endif;
}
```

**Method B**

Here you need to edit articles and add `Read More tag (Shift + Alt + T)` in the place where you want to restrict the article visibility.

Edit `single.php`:

```
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

    // Show part of article for visitors.
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) :
        global $more;

        $more = 0;
    endif;

    the_content();
}
```

Edit `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * Change read more link.
 *
 * @return mixed  Sign up page link.
 */
function modify_read_more_link() {

    $url   = wp_login_url(); // Your sign up page url goes here.
    $title = __( 'Login or Sign up to view the rest of the article.', 'text-domain' );

    return sprintf( '<a class="more-link" href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $url ),
        esc_attr( $title ),
        $title
    );
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
```